# Sym link en Laravel

Tags: laravel, storage

Acabo de contratar un hosting para la app y me está llevando más de una tarde arrancar Laravel coreectamente. Ahora parece que lo tengo todo en orden, pero no encuentro forma de linkear la carpeta storage a public_html

No tengo acceso SSH por desgracia, sino ya habría empleado:
php artisan storage:link

Lo que he hecho es crear el siguiente archivo llamado sym.php

```
<?php
$targetFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/storage/app/public';
$linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/public/storage';
symlink($targetFolder,$linkFolder);
echo 'Symlink process successfully completed';
?>
```

Pero no encuentro a dónde me manda la carpeta linkeada.

Mi arbol de archivos es el siguiente

- /carpetas_iniciales_que_trae_de_serie_el_servidor
- /public_html
- /mi_app_laravel*

Y dentro de /mi_app_laravel*

- /app
- /vendor
- /...
- /storage

A ver si alguien da con la tecla. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Lo he MEDIO solucionado de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
$targetFolder = __DIR__.'/../mi_app_laravel/storage';
$linkFolder = __DIR__.'/storage';
symlink($targetFolder,$linkFolder);
echo 'Symlink process successfully completed';
?>
```

Ahora ya tengo en public_html la carpeta storage linkeada.
Pero al entrar en filemanager sigo sin poder ver las imágenes que hay dentro, y cuando las subo de nuevo, al llamarla desde CKEditor me sale un cuadrado en rojo. Esto en modo local no ocurria.

Por si sirve de ayuda:
Al subirla a filemanager no se ve la imagen en sí pero sí que se sube un archivo. Luego al seleccionar este archivo en CKEditor la URL que dispone es:

```
http://mi_app_laravel.es/storage/photos/shares/uT4AFD7ItKqqWXlLWiaEifYwKboTDUsn1RDmZOlK.png
```

Otra cosa rara y que indica que está mal, es que al entrar en filemanager por medio del browse de CKEditor me salen unas imágenes (sin verse la imagen en sí) y luego si entro en

```
 http://mi_app_laravel.es/filemanager
```

Me salen otras.

Estos son mis archivos en filesystem.php

```
    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        ],
    ],


    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],
];
```

¿Debo cambiar algo? El simbolic link estaba ya desde mi localhost, y antes de hacerlo en el servidor ¿influye?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una ruta en tu proyecto que ejecute el comando `php artisan storage:link` y al guardar los cambios en tu servidor solo visita esa ruta y generaras el link como si tuvieras acceso al SSH